# Path in javascript not loading file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, t4mvc, sigma.js

I'm trying to load a gexf file from javascript in my Asp.Net MVC Web Application from inside a View and am not sure why when I run the website, it doesn't find the file I'm looking for even if the path is 'correct'.

http://localhost:55833/Content/les_miserables.gexf is where the file is being looked for and I have the file in my Content folder yet I get the error that it can't be found (404).

I'm using T4MVC to generate the link to http://localhost:55833/Content/les_miserables.gexf in case any of you are unfamiliar. I am sure that this is  link that is being generated because I have just copy and pasted from my Google Chrome browser the path that is returning a 404.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my javascript:

```
<script src="@Links.Scripts.sigma.sigma_parsers_json_min_js"></script>
<script src="@Links.Scripts.sigma.sigma_plugins_animate_min_js"></script>
<script>
  sigma.parsers.gexf(
    '@Links.Content.les_miserables_gexf',
    { // Here is the ID of the DOM element that
      // will contain the graph:
      container: 'sigma-container'
    },
    function(s) {
      // This function will be executed when the
      // graph is displayed, with "s" the related
      // sigma instance.
    }
  );
</script>
```

This is my straightforward html:

```
 <div class="page">
    <div class="page-content padding-30 container-fluid">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="sigma-container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Has the file been added to the project? VS won't host/build a file that isn't "included".

Comment: It has been included for sure and the project has been built, I'm pretty familiar with including/excluding files and building when adding. I'm still not sure what's going on.